# Terminology: Name for general, non-differential equations over $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, definition, systems-of-equations

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a variable, and $f_1, \ldots , f_n : \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions, each having a closed form expression. Assume that we want to solve the system $f_i(x) = 0$ where $1 \leq i \leq n$. Is there a specific name for such a system? I am in need of a "name", because I will be continually referring to this setting in writing. I tried to come up with things of the form "a system of **_____** equations", but I couldn't find a good one.

*Remark*: Initially, I considered using the adjective "non-differential", but it sounded weird to me. I am currently using "algebraical" equations, but this is probably a bad choice. The term "algebraic" has a well defined meaning, and $f_i$ need not be algebraic in general. I can say "transcendental", but $f_i$ need not always include transcendental terms either.

*Note*: There are no restrictions on $f_i$, other than the stipulation that each have a [closed form expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). In summary, I require $f_i$ to have finitely many terms, each involving elementary functions.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ being a closed form expression. It's obvious when $n=1$, but for $n>1$ it is unclear imho.

Comment: @NateIverson : How is it obvious for $n=1$?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

Comment: @NateIverson I know, but still, this remains very ad-hoc.

Comment: @NateIverson: Does my edits clarify the question?

Comment: @iheap : What about a "system of closed form equations". For all I know such a name is not already fixed in stone, go for it. Your edit -did- clarify the question. And yes algebraic is a very bad choice, just as transcendental. +1

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Thanks for the suggestion. It sounds good. Its only problem is that it doesn't make it obvious that our system does not consist of DE's.

Comment: @iheap : The best way to clear this out is to define it once and for all and then keep using the name.